# How can I point a dns name to an elastic ip when a port number is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, shiny-server

I have recently set up a shiny server account on AWS. I have an elastic ip in the format 
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx but I need to add the port number :3838 to view it on the web

I wish to associate a dns name mywebsite.com with the elastic ip but obviously do not want to have a user add :3838 each time. I tried, with go daddy, associating the name with elastic ip+:3838 but that is invalid

TIA

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't running your web site on a standard port?

Comment: Here's a guide for changing the port number of Shiny Server: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#host-a-directory-of-applications-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work on ubuntu you can use [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3838
```

This will route all traffic coming from port 80 to port 3838

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a reverse proxy on your server.  You can do it with Apache or nginx.

With Apache you can add something like this in your configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:3838/
            ProxyPassReverse / https://172.0.0.1:3838/

</VirtualHost>
```

With nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3838;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            static.example.com;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to need a little more hand holding as I'm new to all this. I have installed Apache2 on Ubuntu. Is it the file apache2.conf that I should be downloading/amending/uploading? My elastic IP is 54.201.204.113. Do I just sub that in for the 172.0.0.1 above?

Comment: Assuming you are running Ubuntu, the file that you'd want to modify is /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Comment: I actually have 2 files in the sites-available folder 000-default.conf and defaut-ssl.conf. I downloaded them both to my local computer amended them with http://54.201.204.113 and reuploaded them. I then attempted to access in browser. Stll needed to add :3838 to view page. Have I missed anything out?

Comment: You need to restart apache or nginx before you configs take into effect.